# Clicking on a clickable image inside a DIV shouldn't affect the DIV itself

Tags: jquery, css, image, html

I have an image inside a `div`. The `div` has to resize on click so I'm using jQuery to toggle its class with different height.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

But I also need to insert an image into the div with `a href` which will open a lightbox. Clicking on the image not only opens the lightbox but also expands the div under it. Is there a way how clicking on the image wouldn't affect the div? I have tried `z-index` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the click really **had** to go through the DOM structure so it would trigger the jQuery lightbox. Inserting `div class="toggle"` into `div class="class"` fixed the problem. Then I modified the jQuery:

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('clicked');
$(this).parent().toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

*I'm using parent() because there are multiple instances of `div class="class"`.*

This way `div class="toggle"` is lower in the DOM but is covering the `div class="class"` entirely. Clicking on the toggle will expand/contract both divs equally. The image with `a href` is placed in `div class="class"` so it is higher in the DOM (clicking on it won't fire the toggle action) but visually above both divs (so the lightbox is working like a champ).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) here to prevent `click` event bubble to its parent:

```
$('.class img').on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Since I don't know your HTML markup, I assume that your images are children of your `.class` element.

Comment: your `e` will be undefined

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I couldn't use the e.stopPropagation() function as it would disable the lightbox (the click on the picture had to go through the DOM). I found another solution and posted as an answer to my question.